# Python - replace a pattern of occurrences in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame with a column ('A') as:

```
A
E19
V17
23.12
23.4
23
42
48
```

like this, there are more than a 100k records.

I want to replace all the occurrences starting with `E` and `V` with a number like `300` and replace numbers `(23.4,23.12,...)` with `23`.

The code that I am using:

```
def clean(x):

 x = sub( r'[E|V](\d+)', r'\g<1>3000', x )

 return sub( r'[^\d]', '' , x ) 

df.A.map(clean).astype(float).astype(int)
```

But I get an error..

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Please help!

Comment: These are very simple pandas tasks, please show what have you tried

Comment: def clean(x):
    x = sub( r'[E|V](\d+)', r'\g<1>3000', x )
    return sub( r'[^\d]', '' , x )
df.A.map( clean ).astype(int)

#TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: check out [`pandas.Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html?highlight=str%20startswith#pandas.Series.str.startswith) and [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html?highlight=astype#pandas.Series.astype).  Have a go at it, post your code and then we can provide further advice.

Comment: Please put your code in the question. You can't `astype(int)` from a `float` string but you can `.astype(float).astype(int)` to get an `int`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  [Pandas has excellant documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) ... [Boolean Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

1. [to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) to convert non-numeric type to NaN
2. [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to drop NaN
3. astype to convert type

   `pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce').dropna().astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

By using `startwith`

```
df.A.str.startswith(('E','V')).map({True:300,False:23})
Out[329]: 
0    300
1    300
2     23
3     23
4     23
5     23
6     23
Name: A, dtype: int64
```